# urlread pound sign (#) doesn't work

Tags: matlab, special-characters, urlread

Trying to read in the pricing lists under pricing information tab:

```
urlread( ' http://www.cefconnect.com/Details/Summary.aspx?Ticker=KYE#pricing ' )
```

But in url '#pricing' doesn't help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out by Darin, it's no use adding `#pricing` to the URL. The web page uses client-side techniques to switch between tabs; not something that can be used by `urlread`.

`Summary.aspx` always returns *all* tabs together as one big page. CSS and JavaScript make it *look* like a collection of tabs, when opened in a web browser.

Use the developer toolbar of your web browser to inspect the web page. For example in Google Chrome, just right-click on the section you are interested in, and select 'inspect element'.

I don't know what you are going to do with the result of `urlread`, but you'll probably have to do some parsing to distill the information you need from the HTML clutter.

Please note `Summary.aspx` launches additional HTTP requests to retrieve additional data. Use the 'Network' tab of Chrome's developer toolbar to analyze that behavior. For example, the following request is made when you click 'GO' after adjusting the pricing history filter criteria.

> http://www.cefconnect.com/Resources/TableData/?Type=PricingHistory&Cusip=48660P104&param0=1M&param1=06/06/2014

At first, this seems to complicate the whole matter, but it may actually be a great opportunity. You can call `urlread` with the URL above, and get some data in JSON format, which is far less cluttered than HTML. Adjust the parameters to get different data. I'm not sure what `48660P104` is; it might be an internal representation of KYE. You may want to use an initial HTTP request to Summary.aspx to retrieve that code; you'll notice the webpage is littered with URLs containing the same parameter `Cusip`.

Comment: FWIW the `Cusip` is a 9 character unique identifier for financial securities.

Answer (score 0):

The `#` character has a special meaning in an url. It represents the [`fragment identifier`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and the value following it is never sent to the server. Only client side javascript can access it. You will need to [`url encode`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the value if you want to send it to the server:

```
urlread( ' http://www.cefconnect.com/Details/Summary.aspx?Ticker=KYE%23pricing ' )
```

This also stands true for other special characters. You need to properly encode them.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion by using %23, also I've tried ^# to escape it without luck. Even in Chrome browser, when I type url: http://www.cefconnect.com/Details/Summary.aspx?Ticker=KYE#pricing  it won't go to the pricing page, and I have to left click the mouse button.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: You are absolutely right about `#` doing no good here. But URL-encoding it won't help. Effectively you are passing the hash to the aspx (it will see a value `KYE#pricing` in parameter `Ticker`), which is not going to work out well.